# execution error when opening Jupyter notebook through terminal

Tags: macos, anaconda, jupyter

I install Jupyter notebook with anaconda, and then to open Jupyter notebook in iterm2 on my Mac. However, some error occurs:

```
[I 23:55:35.354 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 23:55:35.354 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:http://localhost:8888/?    token=cd4638d30319d5e08fc7aebf56f395e5e3b88967c82798a3
[I 23:55:35.354 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 23:55:35.364 NotebookApp]

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=cd4638d30319d5e08fc7aebf56f395e5e3b88967c82798a3
0:97: execution error: “"http://localhost:8888/tree?token=6ff6e52b1c221edfae2dede83f5cdc282959679ee4c5e3a5"”不理解“open location”信息。 (-1708)
```

The Chinese information at last means' can't understand the information of 'open location''.

Who can help me to settle this, thanks.

ps. If I input the address in safari, I can get in the page of Jupyter notebook and use it without any problem. But why couldn't I open Jupiter notebook through the terminal?

Comment: How did you launch Jupyter? Just `$jupyter notebook`? Did you make changes to any configuration files (like `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`)?

Comment: yes, just enter $ Jupyter notebook. and no any change is made

Comment: Thanks, and I has settled this problem, this problem seems to be caused by the update of MACOS, what is ought to do is to edit the configure file of Jupyter notebook and set the default browser to launch Jupyter notebook as u'Safari'